# Insert empty row to a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to insert rows and columns into a table using jquery.

When I insert a row the data from the last row clones with it.

How can I insert the row without the data?
Below is the jquery and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/4kb3p7qz/).

Thanks for any help.

```
$('#irow').click(function(){
   $('#mtable tbody').append($("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone());  
var rowCount = $('#mtable tr').length;
$("#rowcount").text(rowCount)   
});

$('#icol').click(function(){ 
    $('#mtable tr').append($("<td class='container'>"));
    $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
    $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function()      {$(this).children('td:last').append($(''))});

 var col = $('#mtable tbody tr:first > td').length;
$("#colcount").text(col);    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clone row, append then clear all cells in the clone, try :

```
$("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone().appendTo('#mtable tbody').find("td").empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using clone(); Create a new empty element instead.

```
$('#mtable tbody').append($("<tr><td class=\"containter\"></td>td class=\"containter\"></td>td class=\"containter\"></td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about below?

```
<script>
$('#irow').click(function(){
   $('#mtable tbody').append('<tr><td></td>....</tr>'); // AS MUCH AS TD YOU WNAT  
var rowCount = $('#mtable tr').length;
$("#rowcount").text(rowCount)   
});
</script>
```

Clone will duplicate the entire row with data.

Answer (score 0):

empty the id before appending.

```
$('#mtable tbody').empty();// to empty
$("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone().appendTo('#mtable tbody')// then append
```